# Displaying field from model1 in the tree view of model2

Tags: python, python-2.7, odoo, odoo-10

I want to display the field from payroll.adjustment.lines which is employee_id and display it from the tree view of payroll.adjustment model. Is it possible? They have relation.

from payroll.adjustment model

```
adjustment_lines = 
fields.One2many('payroll.adjustment.lines','adj_id',string="Adjustment 
lines")
```

from payroll.adjustment.lines model

```
adj_id = fields.Many2one('payroll.adjustment',string="Payroll 
Adjustment",ondelete='cascade')
```

and in my xml

```
<record id="payroll_adjustment_tree_view" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">payroll_adjustment.tree</field>
        <field name="model">payroll.adjustment</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <tree string="Payroll Adjustment" colors="red:state == 
            'void';green:state == 'draft';blue:state=='confirm'">
                <field name="doc_num"/>
                <field name="company_id"/>
                <field name="adjustment_lines"/>
                <field name="date_from"/>
                <field name="date_to"/>
                <field name="state"/>
            </tree>
        </field>
    </record>
```

the

```
<field name="adjustment_lines"/>
```

only display (2 records) not the employee name. Please help me guys. Thanks

I tried the answered below and this is the result. The employee name displaying false

[image: Result]

and this is my tree view where i called the field from lines and display it to tree view from my payroll.adjustment model.

[image: tree view code]

and this is the output of my tree view and it only shows (records)

[image: tree view output]

Answer (score 1):

It could work, when you override the `name_get()` method of model `payroll.adjustment.line`. Following code example is hopefully self explanory and a general example for your case:

```py
from odoo import models, fields, api


class MyModel(models.Model):
    _name = "my.model"

    another_model_ids = fields.One2Many(
        comodel_name="another.model", inverse="my_model_id",
        string="Another Model Entries")


class AnotherModel(models.Model):
    _name = "another.model"

    my_model_id = fields.Many2One(
        comodel_name="my.model", string="My Model")
    number = fields.Integer(string="A Number")
    yet_another_model_id = fields.Many2One(
        comodel_name="yet.another.model", string="Yet Another Model")

    @api.multi
    def name_get(self):
        # with context flags you can implement multiple
        # possibilities of name generation
        # best example: res.partner
        res = []
        for another_model in self:
            res.append((another_model.id, "{} {}".format(
                another_model.number,
                another_model.yet_another_model_id.name)))
        return res


class YetAnotherModel(models.Model):
    _name = "yet.another.model"

    name = fields.Char(string="Name")
```

`my.model` would be your `payroll.adjustment`, `another.model` the line and `yet.another.model` would be `hr.employee` the model behind `employee_id`.

Comment: The field that i called on XML is another_model_ids(adjustment_lines) where given me same result which is (2 records). What field did I to call on XML? sorry I'm new in Odoo or please give me some useful links so that i will learn it. Thanks for your effort sir

Comment: Could you share a Screenshot of your tree view in your question?

Comment: i meant a screenshot of the client showing the tree, sorry for not being specific enough ;-)

Comment: Oh i totally missed, that you have a one2many field to show in a tree view here. You can try out 2 things: At first try to use widget `many2many_tags` for the field `adjustmend_lines`. If that doesn't work, because the widget isn't working pretty well with a one2many field, than add a computed field to `my.model` which will create a comma-separated string of all lines to present them in tree views.

Comment: Thanks man @CZoellner. Already solved it. I did was creating write function and a loop inside of it with a list, and every loop it will append to the var_list. Also my friends in FB helped me. Thanks for your effort and time.